# How to create a hash file of a .dmg file for use in JTR?

Tags: hash, password-cracking, john-the-ripper, disk-image

I have a .dmg file on my MacBook. I have forgotten the password of the .dmg file and now I'm not able to access the files in it.

I tried using John the Ripper. However, whenever I run `john --format=dmg-opencl (*insert filename here)`, I always get the error "No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)".

I tried saving the hash in .txt file format. The file contained what does not look like a hash (series of letters and numbers) but it looks like a directory.

I think the issue is the hash file that is not properly created.

Please help in cracking the password of my .dmg file.

Comment: "I tried saving the hash in .txt file format. " -- what does that mean? what did you do? How did you create the hash file? "insert filename here" -- what file did you supply?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the hash from the file and then run `john` on the extracted hash.

You can use `dmg2john` to do that.
If that does not work, could you share a snippet of the file you're passing to `john`? Just the output of `xxd <filename.dmg>| head`.

I've found a guide for you here:
https://calvin.me/cracking-passwords-on-macos/

Comment: Apologies, I missed this. I still haven't retrieved my files. How do I share a snippet of the file?